# Why does the sandstone in Yehliu and other scenic coastal northern Taiwan look like vanilla fudge swirl ice cream?

Tags: rocks, sedimentology

I had the photos below handy from a recent trip, but in other areas of northern taiwan you can see very long, thin sheets of this dark, rust-like "chocolate swirl" separating very large, fairly homogenous chunks (several meters square by who knows how deep) of "vanilla" sandstone.

It looks a lot like rust - for example an old, low quality steel or iron plate that's been rusting in a field for so long that it's beginning to disintegrate, but attempts to find signs of magnetism (hold a small magnet to it to feel for attraction, or pass a cellphone over it while looking for deviations in the compass from internal magnetometer) are always negative.

**Question:** Why does the sandstone in Yehliu and other scenic coastal northern Taiwan look like vanilla fudge swirl ice cream?

I'm interested in the processes that make these thin, durable sheets that often seem to erode more slowly than surrounding sandstone and give them a non-sandy structure, and of course what these types of things are called.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yehliu
- https://eng.taiwan.net.tw/m1.aspx?sNo=0002091&id=155
- https://goo.gl/maps/TVtuE9BpT556nsNW9
- https://geohack.toolforge.org/geohack.php?pagename=Yehliu&params=25.2131_N_121.698_E_source:kolossus-frwiki

---

[image: snapshot from Yeiliu in northern Taiwan]

For the images below (1 to 2 MB each) click for full size:

[image: snapshot from Yeiliu in northern Taiwan] [image: snapshot from Yeiliu in northern Taiwan]
[image: snapshot from Yeiliu in northern Taiwan] [image: snapshot from Yeiliu in northern Taiwan]
[image: snapshot from Yeiliu in northern Taiwan] [image: snapshot from Yeiliu in northern Taiwan]

Comment: There seems to be an explanation here (page 4), but I'd rather let a proper sedimentologist answer: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316996747_The_Northeast_Coast_of_Taiwan_intra-workshop_field_guide_May_1_2017